# DPM in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, power-management, radeon

I've read that  AMD Radeon driver got dynamic power management support with Linux which means that the GPU and memory clocks adjust dynamically based on load which is very useful for saving power. So my question is how to do that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find your answer [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-enable-amd-radeon-dynamic-power.html).

They state the following:

To enable DPM in Ubuntu 13.10, you need to open /etc/default/grub with a text editor

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And in this file, search for the following line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

After "splash" add a space and then add this:

```
radeon.dpm=1
```

Save the file and run the following command to update the Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot

Comment: I'll try it but anyway thank

Comment: @nightnoon Don't forget to mark as answer if everything goes well